# How to copy textarea content into clipboard in Angular application

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a `textarea` in an Angular 7 application and I need to copy its content to the clipboard upon clicking on a button. I use this code on the button's click handler:

```
if (this.txtConfigFile) {
    // Select textarea text
    this.txtConfigFile.nativeElement.select();

    // Copy to the clipboard
    document.execCommand("copy");

    // The following lines (in theory) unselect the text (DON'T WORK)
    this.txtConfigFile.nativeElement.value = this.txtConfigFile.nativeElement.value;
    this.txtConfigFile.nativeElement.blur();
}
```

NOTE: `txtConfigFile` is the reference to the textarea element, which I get using `@ViewChild` in the component's declaration:

```
@ViewChild('txtConfigFile') txtConfigFile: ElementRef;
```

This works fine, but the text-area text remains selected, and I'd like to avoid this. After copying the text to the clipboard, how can I unselect it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Instead add `this.txtConfigFile.nativeElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);` after selecting your text to deselect it :

```
 if (this.txtConfigFile) {
  // Select textarea text
  this.txtConfigFile.nativeElement.select();

  // Copy to the clipboard
  document.execCommand("copy");

  // Deselect selected textarea
  this.txtConfigFile.nativeElement.setSelectionRange(0, 0);

}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tmnmva?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)**